# How to detect if a desktop app is installed from a UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, launcher

I'm basically asking the same question as this person on MSDN: [How to detect if application is installed on the device](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/debfb69a-7a35-4a20-9ee3-bf471137d276/uwphow-to-detect-if-application-is-installed-on-the-device?forum=wpdevelop)

However, I am new to Development and the answer was pointed back to Docs.microsoft.com which I was glad, but I guess I got lost in how to pull it off.

I'm assuming this code needs to reside on App.xaml.cs, and that it actually sets a property that I can use to turn on or off the visibility of my View's button.

```
public static IAsyncOperation<LaunchQuerySupportStatus> 
    QueryUriSupportAsync(Windows.Foundation.Uri,Windows.System.LaunchQuerySupportType,System.String)
```

What I want to do, is Mark the visibility of one of my Views within the app, to NOT be shown if Microsoft Dyanmics AX is installed.

Here is Code in XAML for button.

```
<Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ClearHistory="True" PageType="views:DevicePage">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                Height="48"
                Symbol="Keyboard" />
    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="Manage Device" />
</StackPanel>
```

BTW, I'm using Template10 as a framework. So i'm assuming that since all of my Views are displayed within the `Shell.xaml` I would put a Condition on the above button as `Visibility=Visible`.

Comment: Realistically this has nothing to do with T10 either, but basic design.  Unfortunately, unless MS Dynamics AX is a UWP app you will probably be SOL. Ultimately this is something that won't work since the design of UWP prevents you from working in directories outside of your profile.

Comment: Well that is the confusing part.. the first link I added had this as the answer...

Comment: Well that is the confusing part.. the first link I added had this as the answer... A Universal Windows app CAN call Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync to see if the app is installed which supports the URI and package you want to launch.  I'm I not fully understanding what that is saying. To me it says a UWP can call the <LaunchQuerySupportStatus> and get back Available or AppNotInstalled . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launchquerysupportstatus

Comment: Simple UWP -> UWP yes, UWP -> WIn32 not able.

Comment: Since I don't know MS Dynamics does it have a Win32 client or a UWP app? Since attempting to go down the road of discovery and only finding out what you searched was pointless is a complete waste of time.  That is why I originally stated that unless MS Dynamics AX is a UWP that it won't work.

Comment: Dynamics is a Win32 client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to the question as articulated is: no, a UWP cannot detect what Win32 apps are installed on the system.

Slightly longer answer: if what you really want to know is whether an app is installed that supports a specific protocol or supports a specific file type, you can find that out using QueryUriSupportAsync or QueryFileSupportAsync. These APIs also consider installed Win32 apps.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: I've a similar question, in reverse order, posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e452a8a3-80e4-4399-9116-f5fe966c8c76/using-c-how-can-i-detect-if-my-uwp-app-is-installed-on-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop) on an `MSD forum`. Would you have time to share your thoughts and/or a suggestion/comments.

Comment: Post a new question on SO and I will answer it :-)

Comment: Per your suggestion, I've posted the question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54369640/1232087).

Comment: I have posted an answer