# C# - Check if a UWP app is installed on Windows10

Tags: c#, uwp

**Question**: Using `C#` how can we check if a `UWP` application is installed on `Windows`10`

**Possible Goal**: My real motivation is to develop an MS Office app in `VS2017`using [Microsoft.Office.Interop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/) that interacts with a UWP app like [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Office%20Interop) explained [here](https://stefanwick.com/2017/05/26/uwp-calling-office-interop-apis/). But the office app would first check if the required UWP app is installed or not.

For the old Windows 32bit and 64bit apps, we could check if an application is installed using various methods such as the following. I was wondering if there is something similar for UWP on Windows 10:

```
private static bool IsSoftwareInstalled(string softwareName)
{
    var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") ??
              Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                  @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

    if (key == null)
        return false;

    return key.GetSubKeyNames()
        .Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName))
        .Select(subkey => subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string)
        .Any(displayName => displayName != null && displayName.Contains(softwareName));
}
```

Then use an `if` statement to call it:

```
if (IsSoftwareInstalled("OpenSSL"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the PackageManager.FindPackageForUser API from the Win32 app to check if the UWP is installed for the current user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackageforuser

Comment: The method you provided above is always returning null. Since the issue requires a new post, I've posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55270248/1232087). I may be missing something or could it have been a bug in the method?

Answer (score 0):

as I didn't have access to the UWP `PackageManager` api I actually just did a simple directory check

```
var appPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Packages", "YourAppId");            

if (Directory.Exists(appPath))
{
    //exists
 }
```